# Do not execute second then() if condition is met in promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have to stop below code from doing anything after if `arkIsEnabled` and we got inside that method. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
return promise
    .then(response => {
        if (arkIsEnabled) {                
           dispatch(createArk(response));
        }
        ...
        return dispatch(operations.getLuft())
    })
    .then(response =>
        dispatch(prepareLuft())
    )
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch(resourceErrorHandler(error));
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `then` inside the line you want to apply it:

```
return promise
    .then(response => {
        if (arkIsEnabled) {                
           return dispatch(createArk(response)); <=== NOTICE THE RETURN HERE
        }
        ...
        return dispatch(operations.getLuft())
          .then(response =>
            dispatch(prepareLuft())
           )
    })
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch(resourceErrorHandler(error));
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `throw` or `Promise.reject` to ignore `then` functions and go `catch` to handle.

```js
        let arkIsEnabled = true;

        let callBackHasToStop = async () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(1))
            .then(r => {
                console.log(r);

                if (arkIsEnabled) {
                    throw "error";
                }

                //do st
                return   ++r;
            })
            .then(r => {
                console.log(r);

                //do st
                return ++r;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                //check error here. If it is thrown from arkIsEnabled. Stop!
                console.log(e);
                if (e === "error")
                    return;

                //do st
                console.log('last dispatch error');
            });


// Other case
        let otherArkIsEnabled = false;

        let callBackHasNotToStop = async () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(1))
            .then(r => {
                console.log(r);

                if (otherArkIsEnabled) {
                    throw "error";
                }

                //do st
                return   ++r;
            })
            .then(r => {
                console.log(r);

                //do st
                return ++r;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                //check error here. If it is thrown from arkIsEnabled. Stop!
                console.log(e);
                if (e === "error")
                    return;

                //do st
                console.log('last dispatch error');
            });

        let call = async () => {
            await callBackHasNotToStop();
            console.log('-------');
            console.log('2 will not return');
            await callBackHasToStop();
        };

        call();
```